# Module is not working on front and not sending emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, forms, 404

I have just created a form with sending email but my module is not working on front end its going to 404 so i am unable to test if my form is working and sending email

My Config.xml file in  app > code > community > Optfirst > ReviewMyCompany > etc

```
<frontend>
<routers>
  <reviews>
    <use>standard</use>
      <args>
        <module>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany</module>
        <frontName>reviews</frontName>
      </args>
  </reviews>
    <emailus>
        <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany</module>
                <frontName>emailus</frontName>
            </args>
    </emailus>
</routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <reviews>
          <file>reviews.xml</file>
        </reviews>
      </updates>
    </layout>
```

And Here is my EmailusController.php file:

```
      <?php

      class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_EmailusController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {

      public function sendemailAction()
    {
    //Fetch submited params
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setBodyText($params['comment']);
    $mail->setFrom($params['email'], $params['name']);
    $mail->addTo('shoaibswl123@gmail.com', 'Some Recipient');
    $mail->setSubject('Test  Module for Magento');
    try {
        $mail->send();
    }        
    catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from Contact.');

    }

    //Redirect back to index action of (this) controller
    $this->_redirect('optfirst_reviewmycompany/');
}
  }
```

and my form action on frontend is this:

```
action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('optfirst_reviewmycompany/') ?>emailus/sendemail" method="post">
```

But its not sending email it just take to 404 page when i submit the form

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are working on a development box:

First of all, you have 2 different routers defined for your extension... while this COULD be possible, I don't think that you are doing it as you intend. **My recommendation:** Pick One (and it should be the same as the rest of the short tags for your extension).

Second, your action is incorrect, and should be:

```
action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('reviews/emailus/sendemail') ?>" method="post">
```

You build the URL based on 3 parts:

1. The module router tag (in your case EITHER `reviews` or `emailus`)
2. The the lowercase subcomponent name of the controller (in your case `emailus`)
3. The name of the action (excluding the `Action()` part)

To clarify, let me give a different example from default Magento:

```
Mage_Paygate_Authorizenet_PaymentController::cancelAction()
```

If you dig into `app/code/core/Mage/Paygate/etc/config.xml` you will see that the module router name is `paygate`, so replace the first part of the controller class like this:

```
paygate/Authorizenet_PaymentController
```

Now for part #2... Controller is stripped out and the rest of the last half is converted FROM camelcase (only modify the first letter for each "word" separated by `_`). So now you end up with:

```
paygate/authorizenet_payment
```

By default the controller will load the index action, and is the same as:

```
paygate/authorizenet_payment/index
```

But we don't want the index action (it doesn't even exist), we want the cancel action:

```
paygate/authorizenet_payment/cancel
```

Now we have the full URL in the format: MODULE/CONTROLLER/ACTION.

In order to test that you are actually reaching the correct controller action, I recommend putting this near the top of the function (temporarily of course):

```
public function sendemailAction()
{
    //Fetch submited params
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    die('<pre>' . print_r($params, true));  // <---- THIS HERE TO TEST
```

Comment: thats fixed now the error is :Unable to send email. Sample of a custom notification error from

Comment: That error is coming straight from your code, its the exception that you caught from `$mail->send()`. Use something like `die($ex->__toString());` instead of your current error handler to see the ACTUAL exception.